# Google Photos - how to enable face recognition in country's of europe where this function is blocked?

Tags: google-photos, face-recognition

how to turn on function called face recognition in Google Photos in europe where it's forbidden? I tried this solution with TunnelBear VPN and others VPN but it's only shows me in settings this function, I enabled and Google Photos start to showing me new album like "People" but still this mechanizm doesn't sort my photos based on the face becase album "People" is all the time empty. I have plenty of photos with people, selfies and etc. but stil it doesn't work. Do you know what is the solution to run this face recognition in europe country's? It's impossible that there is no solution for that because of the usability region. Please help.

Comment: Have you considered changing the country in google account settings? Not that I remember if such questions are asked or not, at the time of set up. Not that they won't know where you are, if you change the country in preferences. But I used Spotify this way before it came to my country.

Comment: Still can I buy Google Store application for my country and can I use my country-related bank cards for subscription if I change the country? There is information that I can change country one time per year, are there any curcial changes for account?

Comment: If there's payment involved, I wouldn't do it. Proceed on your own... sorry.